# Why I can only see a few folders in Windows disk?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, lubuntu, windows, windows-10

I have a computer with dual boot Windows 10 and Lubuntu 20.04. When I try to access to my windows files I can only see a few, the ones that where already there when I installed Lubuntu.

What can I do to see all my files, even the new ones?

Thank you

Note: I'm just using the file explorer with GUI included in Lubuntu by default, I lauch the program and go to the folder by clicking icons, when I get to the folder I want (inside windows partitions), some files and folders are missing but if I boot Windows, they are just there.

Comment: Needs details. How are you trying to SEE these files? What program what steps?

Comment: Please add two screenshots, first, from Windows snipping tool, showing the folder in Windows Explorer, and all the files you can see. Second, from Lubuntu default file explorer you use showing which files you can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the option but to solve all the problems I had, I just reinstalled lubuntu but this time I format the whole disk, so no more Windows for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have the Windows drive checked using the Windows drive checking tools to repair any inconsistency it may have. Then head the following general advise.

*Background*

Files on an MS Window partition are stored on a file system that is formatted as `ntfs`, the file system of Windows. Ubuntu supports this file system for reading and writing, and also has basic file system repair tools.

When you access a Windows file system in Linux, you need to make sure that **the file system is clean**. That means that Windows should have fully closed the file system before you access it with another file system.

Windows, with the feature "faststart" enabled, *does not fully close* the file system, as part of the strategy to boot faster. While that is fine for a file system only used by Windows, it is not if you have another OS that needs to access to the drive.

*Practical advice to keep the partition healthy*

Ensure that the ntfs volume is properly closed and healthy ("clean") before you use it with Ubuntu.

- Disable the option "Fast start" of Windows, so Windows fully shuts down, closing all file systems whenever you turn it off.
- Effectively **Shut down** Windows before switching to Ubuntu. No hibernate!
- Have the drive regularly checked using the Windows drive checking tools.

If you head that advice, you will be able to seamlessly access the volume on Ubuntu. On Ubuntu, the same rule applies: fully shut it down before starting Windows.

Comment: I'll try to disable Fast Start

Comment: I have no FastBoot option in BIOS

Comment: It is not in Bios. It is in MS Windows.